# PHP Array Error: Resource id #4

Tags: php, mysql

The current issue I'm facing is that my MySql tables are not displaying when I type the url: `www.mydoman.com/search-results.php?town=Blackpool` - the results within the venuetbl aren't showing and print error is stating `Resource id #4`

```
<?php
session_start();

include('dbconnect.php');

if(isset($_GET['town']))   {
$town = $_GET['town'];


            mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$passwd")or die("cannot connect"); 
            mysql_select_db("$db")or die("cannot select DB");
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * from venuetbl where town = '$town'") or die("error");        


}
?>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))    { ?>
        <div class="search-results">
            <div class="result">
                <img src="images/<? echo $rows['imageurl']; ?>.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="100" />
                <h2><? echo $rows['name']; ?></h2>
                <p><? echo $rows['description']; ?></p>

                <a class="button" href="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/result.php?id=<? echo $rows['venueid']; ?>">View More</a>
                <a class="button green" href="#">Add To My Venues</a>
            </div><!--END Result-->
        </div><!--END Search Results-->

                    <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: You are fetching into `$row` but in your loop you are accessing `$rows`.

Comment: You _must_ at a minimum call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$town` before passing it to your query. Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection as it is.

Comment: thanks, obviously had lack of sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to echo $rows['SOME_KEY'] instead of $row['SOME_KEY']